# How to remove line numbering when using copernicus.cls

Tags: line-numbering

The [`copernicus.cls` style file](https://publications.copernicus.org/Copernicus_LaTeX_Package.zip) adds line numbering to the manuscript. I would to remove it so I can convert the pdf to word more easily (and thus share with some co-authors), however I can't seem to find the correct option.

Anyone know what is is? I've tried `noline` already. The line numbers are even present when using `final`.

Comment: Did you try to use `\nolinenumbers` just after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: Try removing the manuscript option from documentclass, and add final instead...

Comment: @Sigur this works, please add as an answer :)

Comment: @Lupino no it doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Analyzing the class file we find the command `\nolinenumbers`.

So use it just after `\begin{document}`.